# How to write documentation for saved keyboard macros?

Tags: keyboard-macros

I have recently defined a keyboard macro using `C-x (` and `C-x)`. I then gave the keyboard macro a name using `M-x name-last-kbd-macro RET defined-kbd-macro`. And saved it to a file using `M-x insert-kbd-macro`. When I used `C-h f RET defined-kbd-macro`, under documentation it simply stated that it was a keyboard macro. Is there a way to include a doc string in `fset` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation-Basics.html) describes, you can also put the documentation string into the `function-documentation` property of the symbol of the macro.

Example:

```el
(fset 'defined-kbd-macro
   (kmacro-lambda-form [?I ?  ?a ?m ?  ?a ?  ?m ?a ?c ?r ?o ?.] 0 "%d"))

(put 'defined-kbd-macro 'function-documentation "My own documentation.")
```